# Закрывается Service в фоне

Tags: android, service

Сразу код сервиса:

```
public class PushService extends Service {

LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;
Intent intent;


public PushService() {
    intent = new Intent("ru.jorik.konGor_taxi.new_order");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
            String lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());

            new GeoTask().execute(lon, lat);

            String serverAnswer = "";
            try {
                serverAnswer = new OrdersTask().execute().get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Orders orders = new Gson().fromJson(serverAnswer, Orders.class);
            if (!orders.data.isEmpty()) {
                Order comeOrder = orders.getLastOrder();
                Order existOrder = Driver.orders.getLastOrder();
                    intent.putExtra("numberOrder", comeOrder.number);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
            Driver.orders = orders;
            WorkActivity.refresList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }


    };
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    checkPermission();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10*1000, 0, locationListener);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

public void checkPermission (){
    int pmC = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    if (hasSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION));// разрешение есть
    else // разрешения нету
        // проверка версии api
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){            
        }
}
//проверка полученного разрешения
public boolean hasSelfPermission (Context cont, String perm){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(cont,perm)==0) return true;
    return false;
}

//класс отправки координат на сервер. Ничего не возвращает и не читает ответ сервера
public class GeoTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... coords) {
        Locale locale = new Locale ("ru","RU");
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.DEFAULT, locale);
        String date = df.format(new Date());
        String sendData = "action=addtomap&UserName=" + Driver.name + "&lat=" + coords[1] + "&lon="
                + coords[0] + "&Date=" + date;
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://kongor.arenda-awto.ru/modules/order/server_side.php");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", Driver.session);
            //отправка запроса
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(sendData);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

//класс, который принимает JSON строку от сервера с содеражанием заказов
public class OrdersTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String answer = "empty";
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://server_side.php");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", Driver.session);

            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("anyRequest");
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader;
            try{
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        new GZIPInputStream(new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream()))));
            } catch (IOException e){
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream())));
            }
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            String temp;
            while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(temp);
            }
            answer = buffer.toString();

            connection.disconnect();

            ///* Костыль для исправления ответа сервера
            if (!answer.substring(0, 10).equals("{\"draw\":nu")) {
                answer = "{\"draw\":nu" + answer;
            }
            ///* конец костыля --

        }catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Сервис работает отлично, пока приложение активно. Стоит свернуть приложение - сервис закрывается (перестает проверять GPS и выдает ошибку). В чем тут проблема? и как отлавливать ошибки в сервисе на Android Studio?
С сервисами работаю впервые.

Comment: Единственный вариант обеспечить работу сервиса вне зависимости от жизненного цикла Activity - использовать Foreground Service

Comment: Смысл не совсем такой. Суть в том, чтобы сервис работал в фоне, при свернутом приложении. и закрывался когда закрывается приложение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onStartCommand` должен выглядеть так если нужно чтобы сервис работал в фоне и хотя бы перезапускался

```
  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          //твой код
          return Service.START_STICKY;
  }
```

`START_STICKY` указывает, что сервис должен перезапуститься в случае если был закрыт.

Вообще это как тут уже заметили сервис и приложение работают в одном потоке. При указании флага `START_STICKY` при закрытии приложения сервис умрет и перезапустится, что уже не так уж плохо.

По умолчанию сервисы работают в фоновом режиме, а это значит, что в случае нехватки памяти операционная система начинает смотреть косо в первую очередь на них, что приводит к убийству сервиса системой.
В этом случае единственный вариант сделать сервис не фоновым, то есть вместо `Background` запустить его в `Foreground`. В таком случае его приоритет будет как у нормального приложения, то есть система не будет его пытаться убить даже в случае нехватки памяти.

В Android для этого есть метод [startForeground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

[Есть годный пример Foreground сервиса](http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/)

Comment: Реализовал с помощью startForeground

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что сервис запускается на том же Thread что и приложение. Попробуйте сделать чтобы PushService унаследовал от класса IntentService (он создаёт свой Thread) или запустить собственный Thread в своём Service.

Comment: это не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно прописать в манифесте строчку

```
<service
    android:name=".Имясервиса"
    android:stopWithTask="false">
```